# Search input collapse

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blogs

I have a search input in a blog I'm looking to make. I'm working to make the blog responsive and thus i want everything to collapse to certain sizes as the user resizes the browser. As it is, the search form input in my sidebar is not collapsing and is overflowing out of the aside and div. Below is the code I have so far. What am I missing in terms of making this responsive?

```
 <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

 <!--HEADER--> 
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
        <div align="center">
          <!--NAVIGAIION + LOGO-->
  </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="header">

                     <div id="toplogo top" align="center"><a class="logo" href="#"></a>      </div>

<hr>    


                    <div align="center">
                      <!--navigation list items-->
                     <ul id="topmargin" class="navigation scaling">
          <li class="scaling"><a href="#"></a><img class= "invert"      src="home.png" width="160px" height="55px"></li>
          <li class="scaling"><a href="#"></a><img class="invert" src="about.png"></li>
          <li class="scaling"><a href="#"></a><img class="invert" src="contact.png"></li>
          <li class="scaling"><a href="#"></a><img class="invert" src="work.png"></li>
        </ul>

                      <hr>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div align="center">
          <!--end of NAVIGATION + LOGO-->


  </div>
  <div id="LayoutDiv2" class="clearfix">

        <div id="content">            <p>This is the Content efnoifnegnrorfnoewnfdksncldncksdjcndlscnkdsncldksnclnsdl
          </p>   
        </div>


        <aside>

            <div id="sidebar">

              <div id="sidebar-content">

                <p> This is the Sidebar</p>

        <form  class=action="" id="search-form" method="get">

                <input type="text" value="search"   onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='search'" onfocus="if(this.value=='search')this.value=''"/>

                <input type="hidden" value="submit"/>

          </form>

              </div>

          </div>

        </aside>






 </div><!--end of LayoutDiv2-->



   <div id="LayoutDiv3">
   <hr>

             <footer><!--beginning of FOOTER-->


                    <div class="footer">
                            <p>PETER</p>
                    </div>



 </footer> <!-- end of FOOTER-->

  </div>



   </div><!--end of LayoutDiv1-->





 </div>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <!--end of Grid Container, HEADER, CONTENT, FOOTER-->


 And here is my CSS:

 img, object, embed, video {
max-width: 100%;
 }

 .ie6 img {
width:100%;
 }

 #topmargin{
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 form{
 padding:5px;
 word-wrap:break-word;

 }

 .logo{
background: url(PLUM%20monogram1.png);
display: block;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
transition: all 500ms linear 0s;
width: 56px;
z-index: 2;
margin-top:5px;
}

 .logo:hover{
background-image: url(PLUM%20monogram2.png);
transition: all 300ms linear 0s;
margin-top:5px;

}

 #toplogo{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:10px;
height:100px;
}

 .navigation{
clear: both;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/* [disabled]list-style: none; */
padding: 0px;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
font-size: 1.4em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
display:inline;
}

 li{
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
}

 .scaling{
 min-width:25%;
 display:inline block;

 }

 .invert{
 }

 .invert:hover{
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
transition: all 100ms linear 0s;


 }


 /* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

 .gridContainer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 87.36%;
padding-left: 1.82%;
padding-right: 1.82%;
word-wrap:break-word;

 }
 #LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }

 #LayoutDiv2 {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 }

 p{
 padding:5px;
 }


 body, html {
 height: 100%;
 padding:1px;
 }

 #content{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 width:80%;
 background:#F36;
 height:100%;

 }

 #sidebar{
display: inline-block;
background:#0FC;
float: left;
width: 20%;

word-wrap:break-word;
 }

 #sidebar-content{
 padding:5px;
 overflow:hidden;
word-wrap:break-word;

 }




 .search-input{
 width:70%;
  }

 .footer{
 background:#00F;
 }

 #LayoutDiv3{
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 }

 @media (max-width: 480px) {

gridContainer {
width: 90.675%;
padding-left: 1.1625%;
padding-right: 1.1625%;
word-wrap:break-word;

 }
  #LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }


 #LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }
#LayoutDiv3{ clear: both;  float: left;  margin-left: 0;  width: 100%;  display: block;      }


#sidebar{ clear: both; width: 100%; }
#content{ clear: both; width: 100%; }
 }




 /* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
 .gridContainer {
width: 90.675%;
padding-left: 1.1625%;
padding-right: 1.1625%;
word-wrap:break-word;

}


  #LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }


  #LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }

 #LayoutDiv3 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }





 /* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and  Tablet Layout. */

 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
 .gridContainer {
width: 88.2%;
max-width: 1232px;
padding-left: 0.9%;
padding-right: 0.9%;
margin: auto;
 }
 #LayoutDiv1 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }
 #LayoutDiv2 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }

 #LayoutDiv3 {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
 }


 }
```

I know this may be a lot to look at, but if somebody can help me make this as responsive as possible, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the class .search-input to your search textbox.

```
<input type="text" 
                                       value="search" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='search'" onfocus="if(this.value=='search')this.value=''"
                                       class="search-input" />
```

EDIT: Added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P6sr2/

Comment: I editted as suggested Toan, but it still has problems as I resize. The search input doesnt collapse as I'm looking for it too. How can I get the sidebar to collapse before the search input exceeds the size and overflows?  Below is a fiddle of what I'm working with so far.     http://jsfiddle.net/striderhiryux1/Bkj5j/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks Toan! This is exactly what I was looking for. I see that I needed more descript semantics. I appreciate the help and I'll put this to memory.